# Request screen sharing always by requesting permission

Tags: macos, permission, screen, sharing

Usually, when I request a screen sharing from my colleagues, I get the dialog window asking whether I want to ask for permission or specify a registered account.

I wonder if there's a way to bypass this question and always directly request for permission, so I always save 1 click.

[image]

Comment: What app are you using to request screen sharing?

Comment: The one built in. Screen Sharing from MacOS